# ODBC SQL Server Stored Procedure Not Returning All Rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to use `ExecuteReader` on my stored procedure to get a list of rates. this is the output I am expecting which is from SSMS. I am only getting one row from the reader instead of the 35 I am supposed to be getting.

[image: Rate]

The code I am using to try and achieve this is

```
OdbcCommand ratesCmd = new OdbcCommand("EXEC SP_LABOR_MODELS ?,?", rfqCon);
ratesCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

OdbcParameter initParam = new OdbcParameter("@init", 1);
OdbcParameter calcrefParam = new OdbcParameter("@calcrefid", DBNull.Value);

rfqCon.Open();

ratesCmd.Parameters.Add(initParam);
ratesCmd.Parameters.Add(calcrefParam);

OdbcDataReader ratesReader = ratesCmd.ExecuteReader();
while(ratesReader.Read()) {
   if(reader[0] != DBNull.Value){
   }
   if(reader[1] != DBNull.Value){
      //Fails here & says index was outside the bounds of the array.
      //There should be 35 rows that get returned to the reader.
   }
}
```

I have tried many things like trying to change the way I am calling the execute on the stored procedure like so.

```cs
= new OdbcCommand("{call SP_LABOR_MODELS(?,?)}", rfqCon);
```

Comment: Your procedure generates a resultset containing a single column - correct? You have no second column so reader[1] fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that the records being returned only have a single field, but `reader[1]` is trying to access a second field.  The reader exposes a single record at a time, and the index refers to the column/field within the record.  In the while loop, call to `ratesReader.Read()` will load the next record, and when the end of the record set is reached, the `Read()` method will return false and exit the loop.